# Not able to cover product and procebook in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have simple apex trigger and i am not able to cover these both line,
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong for this test class ?

Apex trigger :

```
trigger testPrdctPB on Opportunity (before insert) {
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.New){
        Product2 pr = [Select Id, Name from Product2 where Name =: 'Test Product 001' Limit 1];
        Pricebook2 prb = [Select Id from Pricebook2 where Name = 'Test PB' Limit 1];
    }
}
```

Apex test class :

```
@isTest
public class TestSample {

private static testMethod void unitTest1(){

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test Account 001';
    insert acc;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity 001';
    opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
    opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
    opp.StageName = 'Qualification';
    insert opp;

    Pricebook2 standardPricebook = new Pricebook2(
        Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
        IsActive = true);
    update standardPricebook;

    standardPricebook = [SELECT IsStandard FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Id = :standardPricebook.Id];

    Product2 testProduct = new Product2(
        Name = 'Product Test 001', 
        IsActive = true);
    insert testProduct;

    PricebookEntry testPbe = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id = standardPricebook.Id,
        Product2Id = testProduct.Id,
        UnitPrice = 100,
        IsActive = true);
    insert testPbe;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @NailDavid. You should insert your opportunity at the end of your test. The trigger is fired before the insertion of the product. Also you don't insert the pricebook with the name 'Test PB' in your test.

Comment: I have question @MartinLezer , If i am not wrong ,if he insert opportunity before product also. its should reach "Product2 pr and Pricebook2 prb" , Only thing is  "pr and prb " is null. But still its reaches code right ?

Comment: @NITHESHK Yes exactly! I think he just used the wrong term. He didn't want to say reach. This was just not working.

Comment: Yes i got so confused, What could be the reason for not reaching.  Thank You @MartinLezer

Comment: @MartinLezer One more question, StandardPriceBook, Product2, PricebookEntry are ok ? (is this standard way to use in test classes ?)

Comment: @NailDavid Are you sure you need to activate your standard pricebook? You can insert your pricebookentry only by using: `Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId()`

Comment: @MartinLezer What exactly i want is just to cover that line for custom pricebook so, i think you are right i don't need standard pricebook for now.

Comment: *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as **[smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.* -
 [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting the opportunity before creating product and pricebook. Try inserting the opportunity after creating product and pricebook.